# hide .json files when included in Cocoa Touch Framework

Tags: json, swift, cocoa-touch

I would like to release a cocoa touch framework including some json files which contain logic I don't want the framwork's user to see; unfortunately inside the `.framework` file there is still the json visible.

I thought about including it in a swift file:

```
struct JsonProvider {
    static let json = "..."
}
```

but my json is that large that the file isn't usable any more. I didn't find a solution to command line compile and then include it.

Is there a solution to one of the two problems, i.e.

- hide the json inside the framework or
- precompile a swift file and then add it to the framework?

Comment: Put it to a file but encoded, eg using xor encoding. It wont be readable for random user any more

Comment: @Sulthan could you please explain this a little bit more? What kind of file and how can I encode/decode this?

Comment: What you want is obfuscation. There is a thousand of methods to obfuscate data. You can even encrypt it and put the encryption key into your code. Neither will stop someone who will really want to read the data and know how to decompile but it will stop a random curious user.

Comment: @swalkner did my answer help?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this really depends on how secure you need the file to be. Nothing is going to be 100% secure but you can make it more or less difficult for an attacker to gain access.

**Option A: Hide the file**

Add a '.' at the beginning of the file name, which will hide it from those browsing the directory that don't know about hidden files.

Caveats:

- Anyone with knowledge of hidden files can figure this out.

**Option B: Obfuscate**

Encode your file, using Base64 or other encoding methods.

Caveats:

- Only deters the lazy/mildly curious. Encodes are easy to defeat.

**Option C: Encryption or storing in code**

Encrypt the file using a symmetrical algorithm such as AES and store the cipher in code.

Alternatively, remove the json file and create a variable in code with a string that holds the json.

```
var myJson = """
{
 "jsonData": "value"
}
"""
```

Caveats:

- Code can be decompiled to reveal hardcoded strings, but it's difficult. Someone would have to gain access your .ipa file which is protected by Apple's DRM. You could also opt to encode the string, but if someone is already decompiling your code then they can figure out how to defeat obfuscation.

**Option D: Don't include the file at all**

This is a pretty broad topic outside the scope of your question, but essentially you host your file somewhere. Where and how you do this again depends on how secure you need the data to be. Ideally serving the data over HTTPS and blocking self-signed certificates from being used in your app so that it can't be proxied (ie man in the middle).

URLSession already does a pretty good job of this out of the box, but you could take it even further by using certificate pinning: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=g9ejcf8y

Essentially you create certificate configurations on your server and bundle the public keys in your app, the connection will be refused unless the pinning requirements are met. Caveat is that you have to update your app whenever your certificates change.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways:

- You can encrypt that file end decrypt again before using.
- Change json file type to picture or something else to make sure no one know this is JSON file.

Answer (score -1):

You can add json file content to sources as base64 encoded string.

```
struct JSONFiles {
    internal static let fileOneBase64String = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMEAAADLCAYAAADX..."
    static var fileOneJSON: [String: Any] {
        let data = Data(base64Encoded: fileOneBase64String)!
        return try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as!  [String: Any]
    }
}
```

You can use it later anywhere in you framework by

```
print(JSONFiles.fileOneJSON)
```

Hope it help you

UPDATE:
Why as base64 encoded string?

> > > The main benefit base64 encoded string - you don't need to escape special symbols contained in JSON string. Don't need to remove new line symbols/intendation symbols from json string before add to swift source file.
> > >       See example

```
let string: String = "{ \"name\":\"John\", \"email\": \"hello@stackoverflow\" \"age\":30, \"car\":null }"
```

But if json is more complex? If it contains 10 nested levels, arrays, dictionaries?

You can cover by UnitTests that value contained in `fileOneBase64String` can be decoded to JSON object

```
import XCTest
@testable import MyAwesomeFramework

class FrameworkTests: XCTestCase {

    func testThatBase64EncodedJSONStringCanBeDecoded() {
        let data = Data(base64Encoded: JSONFiles.fileOneBase64String)
        XCTAssertNotNil(data, "Unable to convert base64 string to Data")
        do {
            _ = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
        } catch {
            XCTFail("Expected decoded JSON ")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how is that an improvement to just store the json inside the string? Base64 is even longer, right?

Comment: The main benefit you don't need to escape special symbols. This solution allows to store any file type

Comment: And if you will escape symbols in json string then new string will be also bigger then origin json string.